# How to prevent reordering of loads after stores using the C++11 atomics API?

Tags: c++11, atomic

I know that you can use the C++11 atomics API in a producer-consumer context to make sure that a consumer sees the "done writing" flag only after some produced record has been completely written out, i.e.

producer:

```
data[write_index] = <something>
status[write_index].store(READABLE, std::memory_order_release)
```

consumer:

```
if (status[read_index].load(std::memory_order_acquire) == READABLE)
  //do something with data[read_index]
```

My question is what happens next - how does the consumer safely tell the producer that it has finished reading from data[read_index], so that the producer can write to data[read_index] for some other purpose?

On x86, I can do (I think?)

consumer:

```
//do something with data[read_index] //LINE A
asm volatile("" : : : "memory"); //compiler barrier
status[read_index].store(AVAILABLE, std::memory_order_relaxed) //LINE B
```

and

producer:

```
if (status[write_index].load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == AVAILABLE)
  //write_index is available for writing
```

My impression is that on an architecture where loads can be reordered after stores, the writer could observe LINE B before LINE A has finished, which would cause a problem.

Is there a way to do this using the C++11 atomics API? The atomic_thread_fence instructions seemed promising but after reading the documentation I don't see that it gives the guarantee I need here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Always use [sequential consistency](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/memory_order/?kw=memory_order_seq_cst) if in doubt :)

> memory_order_seq_cst
>   The operation is ordered in a sequentially consistent manner: All operations using this memory order are ordered to happen **once all accesses to memory that may have visible side effects** on the other threads involved have already happened.
>   This is the strictest memory order, guaranteeing the least unexpected side effects between thread interactions though the non-atomic memory accesses.

It applies either to the consumer's store which sends the signal back to the producer or the std::atomic_thread_fence before it.

```
void producer() {
  for(;;) {
    data[write_index] = <something>;
    status[write_index].store(READABLE, std::memory_order_release);
    // do something else while consumer reads it

    // producer knows for sure that reader will consume it and signal back
    while( status[write_index].load(std::memory_order_acquire) != WRITEABLE)
        _mm_pause(); // or at least std::this_thread::yield();
  }
}
void consumer() {
    while (status[read_index].load(std::memory_order_acquire) != READABLE)
        _mm_pause(); // or at least std::this_thread::yield();
    //do something with data[read_index]

    // signal back and prevent loads from reorder below
    status[read_index].store(WRITEABLE, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

I'm afraid that this will result in excessive synchronization on x86.. but until someone else comes up with more tricky (but still portable C++11) approach, consider this as the price of portability.

Comment: Could you comment on where in the documentation it states that the compiler can't reorder the memory_order_seq_cst before the "do something with data[read_index]?"

Comment: Should not the producer's `status.store(READABLE)` also use `memory_order_seq_cst`, to prevent `data[write_index] = <something>` from being ordered after it?

Comment: @kkm, it's not necessary. `memory_order_release` serves for this purpose of preventing prior writes to be ordered after the atomic store

Comment: Ah, I see. _`memory_order_release` [...] ensures that all writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable_. But why is then the last `memory_order_seq_cst` necessary? What would be a data race if `memory_order_release` was used instead? The same paragraph on `memory_order_release` also says that _no memory accesses in the current thread can be reordered after this store_. If "memory accesses" are meant to include loads (from `data`), then the consumer would hand-off the `data` in a race-free manner by that. Am I misreading it? I feel lost!

Comment: That's why I recommended to use seq_cst if you in doubt or get lost. And benefits of such optimization is rarely visible (unless you are writing your own parallel algorithm consuming most of the CPU time). Release barrier permits other operations to get reordered *before* it - which in this specific case seem safe.